# req is empty after submit form jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My Form in Jade is

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    form(action="create", method="post")
        div.input
            span.label Username
            input(type="text", name="username")
        div.input
            span.label Password
            input(type="password", name="password")
        div.actions
            input(type="submit", value="Create User")
```

and my index.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
app.route('/create')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.render('formUser', {
            title: 'Create User'
        });
    })
    .post(function (req, res) {

        console.log(req);

    });
```

Why my req.body or req.params is empty ? How can I retrive username and password?

Thanks

Comment: try form(action="/create")

Comment: @ChrisL it isn't a problem of route

Comment: did you require a body parser?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I did

Comment: your code is working on my set up so it must be something in your configs, like bodyparser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't enough

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

you Have to add also

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```